# Button in jQuery UI dialog sends ajax request twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is one of those questions that comes up again and again so I'm aware (I think) of the most common pitfalls.

Scenario:

- A dialog box loads dynamic content on a button click
- An event is bound to one of the dialog buttons which sends an ajax request
- once in a blue moon the ajax request gets sent twice

Here is the pertinent code which renders the dialog:

```
$('#dialog-button'). on('click', function() {
    $('#dialog').load('dialog.php', function() { $('#dialog').dialog('open'); }); 
});

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    buttons: [{
        "text": "Save",
        "class": "save",
        "value": "2",
    },{
        "text": "Cancel",
        "icons": { primary: "ui-icon-cancel" },
        "click": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }],
    close : function() { $('.ui-dialog-buttonset .save').unbind(); }
});
```

As you can see, the dialog is initialized but not not automatically opened until `#dialog-button` is clicked, at which time content is pulled via jQuery `load()` into the dialog and it is opened via callback when the html is finished loading.

Inside the dialog a click event is bound to the `.save` button using `one()` which theoretically should not allow more than click event to fire.  I have taken an additional step by setting the button's disabled property to "true" after it is clicked as well as calling jQuery `unbind()` on it when the dialog is closed.

Here is the code which is loaded into the dialog and binds the ajax call to the button:

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonset .save').one('click', function() {
    $('.ui-dialog-buttonset button').prop('disabled',true);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(error) {
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset button').prop('disabled',false);
            if (error) {
                alert(error);
            } else {
                window.location = 'index.php';
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

When the ajax completes the window is either reloaded or an error occurs.  There have been no errors.

My only working theory so far is that somehow the entire dialog is being created twice but I have been thus far unable to make this happen.  Other than that I am completely at a loss.  I am unable to reproduce the problem myself and it only seems to happen approx once every month or so in a web application that is being used daily.  This obviously makes it all the more difficult to debug.

Comment: Just the code provided doesn't have any obvious errors in it (though I'd argue it's bad practice to attach new event handlers through ajax-delivered html). Could you include the relevant HTML and possibly make a MCVE?

Comment: @blgt - I understand why you would ask that but it's not realistic since it's a rather complex (and proprietary) application.  The reason I wait til the dialog html is loaded is because the ajax data is built from the dialog contents at time of click.  How would you recommend doing this instead?

Comment: Event delegation usually the way to go, instead of constantly binding/unbinding event handlers. Do something like `$.ajax({url: $("#dialog").find(".url-holder").data("url-value") /*...*/})` for getting dynamically loaded values out of the html. Anyway I don't think the question is answerable in its current form